# Why we need the --scripts-version command line option for create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am new to React and learning how to properly create new project. Then I came across `--scripts-version` when we create new project with such command:

```
create-react-app new-project --scripts-version
```

Why do we need to use `--scripts-version`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tool [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) is basically a wrapper around a number of tools and configuration options stored in an npm package called [react-scripts](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts).

When you use the `create-react-app` command to create your React app, it uses `react-scripts` to set up your project.

The command line option `--scripts-version` is an advanced feature to change which version of `react-scripts` is used.

If you are not happy with the way `create-react-app` sets up your project, you can fork the `react-scripts` repository, change it and then use your version to create your React apps.