# What exactly is the '--script-version' command line option for create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, npm

[image]While creating a new project of react we use:

creat-react-app HelloWorld --script-version 1.1.5

So what is --script-version in it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why we need the --scripts-version command line option for create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57364042/why-we-need-the-scripts-version-command-line-option-for-create-react-app)

Answer (score 2):

Create React App uses a package called [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) to do a lot of the work in the background.

This argument sets the version of [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) to use